# How to copy all childs except one in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

This [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) explains how to copy files and directories using the `copy` module in Ansible. How to copy all childs except one?

**Discussion**

1. The [options](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html#options) do not clarify how it could be done.
2. Copying all childs individually is not an option as the parent contains more than 100 childs.

Comment: You are falling into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best option would probably to use the [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) module.

> synchronize is a wrapper around the rsync command, meant to make common tasks with rsync easier.

Whereas the `copy` module copies files using Python and is limited in its functionality. There is a Note in the
[copy module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html):

> The “copy” module recursively copy facility does not scale to lots (>hundreds) of files. For alternative, see synchronize module, which is a wrapper around rsync.

With the `synchronize` module it is possible to pass `exclude` patterns via `rsync_opts` to the `rsync` command being executed by Ansible.

```
# Synchronize passing in extra rsync options
synchronize:
    src: /tmp/helloworld
    dest: /var/www/helloword
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=.git"
```

But the `synchronize` module has some [caveats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#notes). Like the the requirement of `rsync` installed on local and remote machine. That's why I wouldn't use it when not needed.

Answer (score 8):

If I had to use just `copy`, here is what I would do. In this example I am using `patterns` that are specific to Python and a `.hiddenfile` (I'm using hidden to demonstrate find has a lot of options to explore). However the basic idea - you can go wild with patterns/regex filters to meet your needs.

```
- name: prepare a list of files to copy from some place
  find:
    paths: /var/some-place
    hidden: yes
    patterns:
      - "*.py"
      - ".hiddenfile"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: target_files

- name: copy files to other place
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: /var/other-place
  with_items: "{{ target_files.files }}"
  tags:
    - copy
```

Comment: answer is awesome, worked perfectly for me. We can also exclude some files in the find module with: excludes: 'string'